# How do I use IsError on a function value, instead of cell value?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column in a sheet with unformatted date values. There are three types, always leading off with the month abbreviation:

```
JAN/19
JAN02/19
JAN19
```

I'm writing a macro to loop through the column and format these as dates. `JAN/19` and `JAN19` will both just be set to the first day of the month, whereas `JAN02/19` will be set as `01/02/19`.

In order to error handle for column headings and potential blank rows at the top, I want to take the left three characters and see if they are a month abbreviation. I'm trying to use the below code:

```
If IsError(DateValue("01 " & Left(Cells(1, 1), 3) & " 19")) = True Then

     MsgBox "Oops, " & Left(Cells(1, 1), 3) & " is not a valid month abbreviation"

End If
```

It skips the message box if `Left(Cells(1, 1), 3)` is a valid month abbreviation, but then gives this error if it isn't, instead of the `MsgBox` message.

[image]

Comment: `Dim Test As Variant` `Test = DateValue("01 " & Left(Cells(1, 1), 3) & " 19")`and then: `If IsError(Test) Then` try it like that.

Comment: @Damian same mistake as Vityata - see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56154055/how-do-i-use-iserror-on-a-function-value-instead-of-cell-value/56154425#comment98938183_56154189)

Comment: You are right @MathieuGuindon

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IsDate()` is a rather handy function, which should work as intended:

```
Sub TestMe()

    If IsDate("01 " & Left(Cells(1, 1), 3) & " 19") Then
        Debug.Print "It is a date!"
    Else
        Debug.Print "Oops, " & Left(Cells(1, 1), 3) & " is not a valid month abbreviation"
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: But it won't: if `Cells(1, 1)` is a `Variant/Error`, then `Left(Cells(1, 1), 3)` is coercing it into a `Variant/String`, and that's where the *type mismatch* error is thrown - well before `IsDate` gets to even run.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon - True, I was only testing the input from the question :)

Comment: I think I might have misread the question... I can't repro the type mismatch given OP's inputs, I just assumed the type mismatch was caused by a `Variant/Error` cell somewhere; I do get the error given a cell error for input.

Comment: Apologies on that. The cell will NEVER be `Variant/Error`, only the result of using the first three characters as a month. So I believe the `IsDate()` should work.

Comment: @sethW fair enough. note that you should NEVER assume anything about the variant subtype of a cell's value.

Comment: @sethW apologies, I got confused with `IsDate` here vs `DateValue` in the OP - `DateValue` *does* throw a type mismatch given non-date inputs. Point stands for variant subtype assumptions though.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon you're right. In my efforts to not over-explain, I perhaps left out some clarifications that could have helped. Either way, `IsDate()` works best for this scenario.

Comment: @sethW no, your post was fine, the reading fail is entirely on me :)

Answer (score 2):

`Error` is a data type.

The `IsError` function is used to determine whether a `Variant` has a variant subtype `Error`, i.e. whether a given value is a `Variant/Error`.

In Excel, you get a `Variant/Error` value when you read a cell containing e.g. `#VALUE!`. Programmatically, you can get a `Variant/Error` using the `CVErr` function together with Excel errors enum values, for example:

```
Debug.Print IsError(CVErr(xlErrNA)) ' #N/A cell error
```

The problem in this expression:

> ```
> If IsError(DateValue("01 " & Left(Cells(1, 1), 3) & " 19")) = True Then
> ```

..is that `IsError` is given a `Date`, so the function will always return `False` (`= True` is redundant).

But `IsError` doesn't even get to be evaluated: its arguments need to be evaluated first, and that's where the *type mismatch* error is:

```
Left(Cells(1, 1), 3)
```

If `Cells(1, 1)` contains a `Variant/Error` value, then coercing it into a `String` throws the *type mismatch* error that you're getting, because an `Error` can't be implicitly (or explicitly) converted to any other data type.

The solution is to pull `Cells(1, 1)` into its own local `Variant` variable:

```
Dim cellValue As Variant
cellValue = ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).Value 'note: made qualifier and member call explicit
```

Then you can evaluate whether that value is an `Error`:

```
If Not IsError(cellValue) Then
    If IsDate("01 " & Left(cellValue, 3) & " 19") Then
        ' we're looking at a valid date value that VBA can convert to a Date data type
    Else
        ' we're looking at a malformed date
    End If
Else
    ' cellValue is a Variant/Error that we can't use.
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

IsError() will not catch a type mismatch. You would need to do a run-time error handler to catch an error like that after it's happened.

On the other hand, for this use case you could use IsNumeric() instead of IsError (). I recommend something like this:

```
If Not (IsNumeric(Left(Cells(1, 1), 3))) Then    
    MsgBox "Oops, " & Left(Cells(1, 1), 3) & " is not a valid month abbreviation"   
End If
```